# Google Apps - Unable to receive emails on same domain despite SPF and DKIM confirmed

Tags: dns, gmail, google-workspace, dkim, spf

We're developing a site that will be sending emails from `noreply@domain.com` (this email account doesn't exist) to `name@domain.com`.

`domain.com` has emails served via `Google Apps`; the `MX`, `SPF` and `DKIM` are all set up and marked as passed when testing.

The issue is that no emails sent via our system from `noreply@domain.com` are going to `name@domain.com`. Nothing appears in the inbox or the spam, nothing is being delivered at all and I'm banging my head against a brick wall over this issue as I feel I have done everything I can to sort this.

http://www.mail-tester.com/web-7U5MIT - as you'll need some context this is a site I used to test it all.

Comment: How is your system sending emails? SMTP? PHP mail?

Comment: I'm at home at the mo but I believe it's PHP Mail

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Is PHP actually sending the e-mail? Have you been able to send that same e-mail to another address outside of that domain?

Comment: Yeah the email is being sent becuase it comes to my personal gmail absolutely fine. It's definitely something to do with sending and receiving on the same domain

Comment: Is your SPF record too limited? By that I mean - does it only allow Google App's servers to send mail, have you allowed the server to send e-mail using your domain as well? You probably would have to add the server's IP to the SPF record.

Comment: ip4 address has been added to the SPF for the sending server. Like i say, everything passes properly, but no delivery on same domain as sending

Comment: Raw audit logs on Google Apps side showing anything?

Comment: Nothing in there at all :/

Comment: I think i'm going to try sending mail via mailgun.com to see if that eliminates the issue

Comment: Did it work with Mailgun?

Comment: I totally forgot to get back to you on this. Mailgun fixed it for sure, i guess having that 3rd party made life easier